# How display UIImage in swift using struct

Tags: swift, struct

Im having problems with UIImage, Im trying to display and image into the Image View but im having problems with my struct... can some one help me here is my code.

```
import UIKit

struct Question {
    var Question: String!
    var Answers: [String]!
    var Answer: Int!
    var Img: UIImage?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Buttons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView! //This part Im pretty sure that i need to connect to the var Img:UIImage? but Im not sure how?

//Creation of a variable to hold the Quesitons,Question Number and Answer Number

var Questions = [Question]()
var questionNumber = Int()
var answerNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Creation of the Question
    Questions = [Question(Question: "Who is this guy?", Answers: ["Alex","Roberto","Joey","Will"], Answer: 2, Img: UIImage.self(named:"steve_jobs"))]

    //We call our funciton into the viewDidLoad
    pickQuestion()
}
```

Comment: "im having problems with my struct".  What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I want to display the image into the question, but the thing is i dont know how link the Img property to the UIImgView in this case is call imgView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the image from the struct to set the image property of the UIImageView:

```
imgView.image = Questions[questionNumber].Img
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was trying to do something similar but my problem was the last dot.... thank you so much

Comment: @RobertoViramontes yw